# How to bootstrap count data in R (EcosimR ???)

Tags: r

Im working through a project that is due imminently and I have almost zero idea how to use R, so was wondering if someone could lay out a step by step of how to bootstrap my data. I have data comparing the diet of 2 carnivore species, each species is feeding on 16 different prey items (almost all the same). I want to test whether these observed values (attributed to the frequency of each prey item) are significant vs. randomly generated (1000 bootstrap iterations) values. I have very little idea of how to do it.

Comment: Help him, guys! Anyone can close this type of questions, but this one really needs help.

Comment: you need to reword your question. Write your R code that defines your 2 carnivore species. When asking on SO, you need to show what did you try. This is not a place for doing your homework for you.